# SSIS Escape quotation from CSV file

Tags: ssis, etl

I have an SSIS to import a CSV file to SQL table in the source connection using quotation(")as Text Qualifier . In some of the files two columns have extra quotation mark(eg: "Col1"",Col2""") . it is importing to table as one column(Col1",Col2"). Is there any way to escape these quotation and insert the data correctly in two columns?

Comment: The format of the CSV is bad.

Comment: @KeithL Thanks for responding. Is there any way we can process that data?

Comment: it just seems too inconsistent to even try and come up with a manual parser. Regex is where I would look, but I am not certain you will be able to trust any pattern.